# Annotation based validation messages are not displaying in Struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, validation, struts2

I'm using Struts 2 annotation based validation in my project. This is my entity class In this only I validating some fields

```java
public class Vendor implements Serializable {

 private String vendorName;

 public String getVendorName() {
    return vendorName;
}

@RequiredStringValidator(message = "VendorName is Required", type = ValidatorType.FIELD)
public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
    this.vendorName = vendorName;
}

}
```

This is my action class which implements model driven interface

```java
public class AddVendorAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Vendor> {

private Vendor v;

public AddVendorAction() {
    this.v = new Vendor();
}

public String save() {
    System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhWE");
    vd.addVendor(getV());

    return SUCCESS;
}

public String populateItems() {
    leftsideVendorlist = vd.itemSet();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String vendorList() {
    vendorlist = vd.list();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public Vendor getV() {
    return v;
}

public void setV(Vendor v) {
    this.v = v;
}

public List<Vendor> getVendorlist() {
    return vendorlist;
}

public void setVendorlist(List<Vendor> vendorlist) {
    this.vendorlist = vendorlist;
}

@Override
public Vendor getModel() {
    return v;
}
}
```

This is my `struts.xml` file which extends hibernate-default package

```
 <struts>
   <package name="purchasemodule" namespace="/" extends="hibernate-default">    
     <action name="AddVendor" class="com.elegant.purchasemodule.purchasemasters.vendor.AddVendorAction" 
        method="save">            
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <result name="input" type="chain">populateitems</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirect">vendorlist</result>
    </action>
    <action name="vendorlist"  class="com.elegant.purchasemodule.purchasemasters.vendor.AddVendorAction" 
            method="vendorList">
        <result name="success">/VendorList.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="populateitems" class="com.elegant.purchasemodule.purchasemasters.vendor.AddVendorAction" 
            method="populateItems">
        <result name="success">/addvendor.jsp</result>  
        <result name="input" >/addvendor.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package> 
</struts>
```

This is my jsp page

```jsp
<form  action="AddVendor" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Vendor Name</label>  
        <s:textfield name="vendorName" cssClass="form-control input-md"></s:textfield>
        </form>
```

Its not displaying any validation messages.I can't find out what is the problem.Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use visitor field validator on the `model` property

```
@Override
@VisitorFieldValidator(appendPrefix = false)
public Vendor getModel() {
    return v;
}
```

Comment: because `input` result should not be `chain` it should be `dispatcher`, if you want to populate lists do it in `prepare()` method by implementing `Prepareable` or configure `input()` method.

Comment: Thank u and i have seen it. In the above jsp page error messages are showing twice i don't know why. can you help me again by reviewing the code.Thank u so much in advance The help in SO is great.

Comment: If you are using default (xhtml) theme then you don't need to use `s:fielderror` tags, xhtml theme adds error messages and `s:fielderror` also adds messages.

Comment: I tried using simple theme.`s:fielderror` is also displaying messages twice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the suggestions given by @Roman C .Did the changes like this validations are working.In my Action Class Added `@VisitorFieldValidator(appendPrefix = false)`

```
public class AddVendorAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Vendor>,Preparable {
 @Override
@VisitorFieldValidator(appendPrefix = false)
public Vendor getModel() {
    return v;
} 
@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
     leftsideVendorlist = vd.itemSet();
}
}
```

In Struts.xml file added `defaultStack`

```
<action name="AddVendor" 
            class="com.elegant.purchasemodule.purchasemasters.vendor.AddVendorAction" 
            method="save">            
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="input">/addvendor.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirect">vendorlist</result>
    </action>
```

In Jsp page added `<s:error` tag with corresponding field name

```
<s:form  action="AddVendor" method="post" cssClass="form-horizontal" theme="simple">

 <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Vendor Name</label>  
 <s:textfield id="vendorName" name="vendorName" cssClass="form-control input-md"/> 
 <s:fielderror fieldName="vendorName" cssClass="alert-danger"/>
 </s:form>
```

Comment: But In The above code validation error messages are displaying twice, can't able to figure it out why.Can anybody help me.